# Fontes do Google Fonts não sendo aplicadas no React Native

Tags: javascript, css, react-native

Olá,
Sou iniciante no **React Native** e tenho enfrentado problemas na utilização de fontes externas no meu projeto.
Ainda que tenha seguido todos os passos normalmente recomendados em tutoriais, o emulador continua não alterando a fonte de acordo com os estilos.

Minha pasta assets/fonts:
[image]

Meu react-native.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    assets: ['./assets/fonts']
}
```

Meu App.js:

```
import styles from '../../styles.module.css';

export default function App() {

    return (
        <View style={styles['main-container']}>
            <Text style={styles['title'], {fontFamily:"Montserrat Bold"}}>Hello World!</Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Meu styles.module.css:

```
.title {
    font-family: "Montserrat Black";
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

EDIT: A seguinte mensagem sempre é exibida no emulador

```
Overwriting fontFamily style attribute preprocessor
```

Comment: Você executou o `run-android` novamente após instalar essas fontes?

Comment: Sim, restartei a aplicação algumas vezes

Comment: Tentou ver se definir a `font-family` apenas como `Monserrat` ela funciona?

Comment: Sim, porém não funcionou

Comment: Ok, tente renomear o arquivo `Montserrat Medium` para `Montserrat-Medium` (com - no lugar do espaço) e teste colocando apenas `Montserrat`. Outra coisa, você colocou essas fontes também na pasta assets do android?

Comment: Inicialmente, o arquivo .ttf possuía -, contudo não funcionou e optei por deixar somente um espaço. Novamente não funcionou.
Sobre o assets do android, elas já estão lá.

Comment: Veja se estas dicas te ajudam https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825276/how-to-add-custom-font-in-react-native-android
 e https://garbagevalue.com/blog/use-custom-fonts-in-react-native

Comment: Optei por deletar todos os arquivos .ttf externos e seguir o passo a passo do último link que @Bins mandou. Enfim funcionou.
Valeu!

Comment: Optei por deletar todos os arquivos .ttf externos e seguir o passo a passo do último [link](https://garbagevalue.com/blog/use-custom-fonts-in-react-native) que @Bins mandou. Enfim funcionou.
<br><br>